# AWK commands giving different results in different Ubuntu versions

Tags: ubuntu, awk

We are using below `awk` commands to split numbers and alphabets in a alphanumeric text.

```
echo "1.5GB" |awk '{ gsub(/([[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+)/,"&\n",$0) ; print "size="$1"\nsymbol="$2}'
```

This command gives desired result in `Ubuntu 20.04`. Result is

```
size=1.5
symbol=GB
```

But in `Ubuntu 18.04` it gives below result,which is not a desired result

```
size=1.5GB
symbol=
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what is your `awk` version? For my in gawk its working fine. **Run** a `awk -V` command to see your `awk` version once.

Comment: In 20.04 we have : mawk 1.3.4 20200120
In 18.04 we have : mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

Comment: Note the date on your mawk1 command - `Nov 1996`, over a quarter of a century old. Get a new version and, preferably, switch to gawk as even that newer version of mawk1 you have on the other machine doesn't compare to gawk for functionality and is being supplanted by mawk2 which is more fully-featured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 1996 mawk is a minimal-featured version of awk designed for speed of execution. It's not POSIX compliant and so shouldn't be expected to support POSIX character classes. Get a new version if at all possible or change this:

```
/([[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+)/
```

to this:

```
/([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9.-]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)/
```

e.g.:

```
echo "1.5GB" |awk '{ gsub(/([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9.-]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)/,"&\n",$0) ; print "size="$1"\nsymbol="$2}'
size=1.5
symbol=GB
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are getting the desired result. will this code give same result in all different awk versions?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it will for the same locale settings. If, as is extremely unlikely, you end up on a machine with a locale setting such that, for example, there are other characters than digits in the range `0-9` or some digits that are outside of that range then YMMV - that's why character classes exist, to handle such issues, but if your awk doesn't support them then you're out of luck unless you specifically list each character you care about, e.g. `[0123456789]` instead of `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

i can't replicate the issue - all my `awk`'s outputs ended up with the same hashed value :

```
% echo "1.5GB" | nawk '{ print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF; gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+/,"&\n",$0) ; print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF }' | xxh128sum 
1b0095d0c4c02859a61a0ab5a3253b58  stdin

% echo "1.5GB" | mawk '{ print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF; gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+/,"&\n",$0) ; print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF }' | xxh128sum
1b0095d0c4c02859a61a0ab5a3253b58  stdin

% echo "1.5GB" | mawk2 '{ print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF; gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+/,"&\n",$0) ; print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF }' | xxh128sum
1b0095d0c4c02859a61a0ab5a3253b58  stdin

% echo "1.5GB" | gawk -be '{ print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF; gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+/,"&\n",$0) ; print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF }' | xxh128sum
1b0095d0c4c02859a61a0ab5a3253b58  stdin

% echo "1.5GB" | gawk -ne '{ print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF; gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+/,"&\n",$0) ; print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF }' | xxh128sum
1b0095d0c4c02859a61a0ab5a3253b58  stdin

% echo "1.5GB" | gawk -ce '{ print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF; gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+/,"&\n",$0) ; print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF }' | xxh128sum
1b0095d0c4c02859a61a0ab5a3253b58  stdin

% echo "1.5GB" | gawk -Pe '{ print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF; gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+/,"&\n",$0) ; print NR,NF,$0,$1,$NF }' | xxh128sum
1b0095d0c4c02859a61a0ab5a3253b58  stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is unclear what change in mawk 1.3.4 versus 1.3.3 made your code work, the code is logically flawed to begin with if the intent is to display the numeric portion of the input as `size` and the alphabetical portion as `symbol` even when one of the two components is missing, since the call to `gsub` makes whichever alphabetical or numeric characters it gets the first field. For example, if the input is just `GB`, your code will output:

```
size=GB
symbol=
```

which I don't think is desired.

A better approach is to remove the alphabetical portion from the input to make it `size`, and remove the numeric portion from the input to make it `symbol`:

```
awk '{s=$0;sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"",s);sub(/[[:digit:].-]+/,"");print"size="s"\nsymbol="$0}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, we tried this but we are not getting the desired result
`size=1.5GB
symbol=1.5GB`

Comment: Interesting. It works in my mawk 1.3.4 but I have no 1.3.3 to test with.